# bash sort by last occurrence of key

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I want to sort some files marked in the end of every line with @ plus a number. The problem is you can find the @ more than once per line. The file could be something like:

```
'Hello from line 2' @2
'Hello from line 3' @3
'Hi' @5 'Hello from line 1' @1
```

I want my output ordered like this:

```
'Hi' @5 'Hello from line 1' @1
'Hello from line 2' @2
'Hello from line 3' @3
```

But the @5 is obstructing it.I have tested:

```
cat myFile.txt | sort -t@ -k2
```

But @ is not in a specific column, is in the last. I have seen some solutions here in this site using awk but it seems to fail in my case.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Can the numbers be more than single digits?

Comment: Yes @Cyrus the numbers can be more than one digit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) with awk and cut:

```
awk -F '@' '{print $NF,$0}' file | sort -n | cut -d " " -f 2-
```

$NF contains last column.

Output:

```
'Hi' @5 'Hello from line 1' @1
'Hello from line 2' @2
'Hello from line 3' @3
```

Comment: Thanks Cyrus I will use your solution. @RavinderSingh13 thanks for your solution but it does not work with numbers of more than one digit, sorry in my sample I used only one digit numbers, I should clarify that when I did the question. 
I don't understand the -1 in the question, I'm just a newbie using bash, I don't know more than basic commands. Thanks for all the solutions, I will analyze them to learn more about sorting.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following with combination of `rev` + `sort`(written and tested with shown samples and after seeing Cyrus's comment digits are in single digit).

```
rev Input_file | sort -n | rev
```

***Logical explanation:***

- Firstly printing Input_file in reverse order(from last character to first character).
- Now last digits become first field of so passing its output to `sort` command to sort it by numbers.
- Once its sorted then again using `rev` to make Input_file in its actual form.

Answer (score 1):

One in GNU awk that hashes records to a two-dimensional array `a` and for sorting uses `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` to control `for` traversal. First a bit changed sample:

```
b@1
a@3
1@3
a@2
1@4
b@2
a@1
a@4
```

Then the program:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN {
    FS="@"                                        # field separator
}
{
    a[$NF][++c[$NF]]=$0                           # hash records, 1st dim i the 
}                                                 # number, 2nd serial of each 
END {                                             # each number if duplicates
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"          # 1st dim, sort in index value
    for(i in a) {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_str_asc"      # 2nd dim, sort on array value
        for(j in a[i])
            print a[i][j]
        # PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"    # not sure if needed, seems like not
    }
}' file
```

Output:

```
a@1
b@1
a@2
b@2
1@3
a@3
1@4
a@4
```

... or with your data:

```
'Hi' @5 'Hello from line 1' @1
'Hello from line 2' @2
'Hello from line 3' @3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed 's/@\([^@]*\)$/'$'\37''\1/' input.txt | sort -t $'\37' -k2,2n | tr $'\37' '@'
'Hi' @5 'Hello from line 1' @1
Hello from line 2' @2
'Hello from line 3' @3
```

This first replaces the last @ in each line with the ASCII [unit separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#Field_separators) character (Which is very unlikely to appear elsewhere in your input), sorts by the second column using US as the field delimiter, and then finally turns the US back into a @.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution

```
$ cat at.txt | sed -E 's/(@[0-9])$/D\1/' | sort -tD -k2,2 | tr -d 'D'
'Hi' @5 'Hello from line 1' @1
'Hello from line 2' @2
'Hello from line 3' @3
```

Here's the steps I took:

First we add 'D' before the last @ for each line.

```
'Hello from line 2' D@2
'Hello from line 3' D@3
'Hi' @5 'Hello from line 1' D@1
```

Then we sort by the second column with delimiter 'D'.

```
'Hi' @5 'Hello from line 1' D@1
'Hello from line 2' D@2
'Hello from line 3' D@3
```

Lastly, we remove 'D'.

```
'Hi' @5 'Hello from line 1' @1
'Hello from line 2' @2
'Hello from line 3' @3
```

Hope you found this useful.